# Auth0 callback URL for Vue/Quasar and Capacitor app

Tags: vue.js, auth0, capacitor, quasar, auth0-lock

I am trying to setup Auth0 for my Quasar app that will use Capacitor but without success. Mainly i use auth0-lock and it works as expected but if i provide any callback url how will that work when the app is running on the device with Capacitor? For example i provide callback url http://localhost:8080/callback
When the user is running this on a device this callback will not be valid...
Any suggestions how to get Auth0 running for Vue with Capacitor?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Auth0 SPA SDK within a capacitor (angular) app.  I got it to work by leveraging a Custom URL Scheme (e.g. myapp://callback).  This Custom URL Scheme needs to be configured in both iOS and Android projects.  The newer/cooler way to do this is by using Universal/App links.  Either of these options would need to be configured in your Auth0 application to allow the callback URLs.

More info is available on these link setups [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links).